# Keep Getting the error in Restore View Phase

Tags: jsf

Below is the exception that i get.

if i click the hiperlink  ServeResourcePhaseListener.java:96  redirects and says line 96 is a invalid line number.  can you let me know what the issue.

```
- Exception wile retrieving addResource
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.AddResourceFactory.getInstance(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/util/AddResource;
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ServeResourcePhaseListener.beforePhase(ServeResourcePhaseListener.java:96)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:70)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:530)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:266)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:155)
    at jsp_servlet.__index._jspService(__index.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:394)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:309)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3241)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2010)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1916)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
- Exception in PhaseListener RESTORE_VIEW(1) beforePhase.
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.AddResourceFactory.getInstance(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/util/AddResource;
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ServeResourcePhaseListener.beforePhase(ServeResourcePhaseListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:70)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:530)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:266)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:155)
    at jsp_servlet.__index._jspService(__index.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:394)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:309)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3241)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2010)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1916)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ServeResourcePhaseListener` and `AddResourceFactory` are part of Apache Tomahawk; in version 1.1.11 the method it claims not to find [seems to exist](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/myfaces/tomahawk/tomahawk/1.1.11/tomahawk-1.1.11-sources.jar!/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/util/AddResourceFactory.java?format=ok). Is it possible that your classpath contains multiple incompatible versions of Tomahawk?

Comment: Yes you were right. There was one more version of Tomahawk which was causing the issue.  But getting one more error.  can you help with that .

Comment: - Exception in PhaseListener RENDER_RESPONSE(6) beforePhase.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:706)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:576)

Comment: @user1292276: Apparently some problem with a resource bundle definition. Check those in your faces-config.xml and whether the files actually exist: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/

Comment: Was not using any Resource Bundle at all. Not sure why the error was popping up.  But after adding one it worked